# Problema com identificação / function

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 itens à venda e, debaixo de tais, temos botões que levam a function `comprar()`. Ssegue o código:

Item 1:

`<h1 Bola </h1>`
`<p 5 reais /q>`
`<input type="button" value="Comprar" onclick='comprar()'>`

Item 2:

`<h1 Chiclete </h1>`
`<p 2 reais /q>`
`<input type="button" value="Comprar" onclick='comprar()'>`

Qual parâmetro/ argumento eu preciso usar na function `comprar()` para tal identificar qual item eu me refiro?

Comment: Um exemplo: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/AffectionateHarshArguments, bons estudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisaria passar a chave do item.
Algo está montando ele na tela certo? Seja um PHP ou até um AngularJS, não importa, ao montar esta tela, é necessário trazer tb um valor que faça referência ao item.
A função comprar sempre será chamada, então, dentro da função você precisa passar uma variável avisando qual será o item, pode ser o id deste item ( ou até o nome da div, uma vez que cada div precisa ter seu valor único).

Por exemplo:

```
<legend>Item 1:</legend>

<h1> Bola </h1>
<p> 5 reais </p>
<input type="button" value="Comprar" onclick="comprar('1')">

<legend>Item 2:</legend>

<h1> Chiclete </h1>
<p> 2 reais </p>
<input type="button" value="Comprar" onclick="comprar('2')">

function comprar(item){
 //'item' corresponde ao valor passado na chamada da função, no exemplo, 1 ou 2
}
```

Obs: Existem maneiras melhores de fazer isso através do JQuery, por exemplo.

Comment: Após isso eu teria que fazer?:  if (item == 1)  console.log('bola'')  
Pois se for assim eu teria que sempre adicionar um ID manualmente, imagina uma loja com 500 itens.

Comment: Amigo, numa loja de 500 itens, cada item tem seu id individual. Você só terá que adicionar manualmente se estiver criando os itens individualmente. Qual o BD que está salvo estes itens? Os itens devem possuir uma chave primária. Utilize esta chave para fazer referência a ele na página de compra. A questão é que você não monta uma loja só com JS, e o que você postou foi referente somente ao JS. De que maneira os dados vem para sua página? Ajax?.